# Reference of Getter/Setter functions

Tags: dart

I have the following variable and getter / setter defined in my data model:

```dart
class Actor {
    int _x;
    int get x => _x;
    set x(int value) => _x = value;
}
```

And there is this generic class that requires a getter / setter function pointer

```dart
class PropertyItem {
   var getterFunction;
   var setterFunction;
   PropertyItem(this.getterFunction, this.setterFunction);
}
```

How do i pass a reference of the getter / setter function of X to the PropertyItem class?

```dart
// Something like this
var item = new PropertyItem(x.getter, x.setter);
```

EDIT: Updated with a more clear question

Comment: It's one of the core elements of Dart ideology is that you don't use 'empty' getters/setters: if there's a property (either in target class or in its superclass) to be accessed, language will look for its setter/getter method anyway; only if that check has failed, the property will be accessed directly. Can you update your question with more details regarding the class structure?

Comment: raina77ow, Thanks.  Hope the updated question is more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, you don't.
Getters and setters are not extractable - they are indistinguishable from just having a field (if you don't do side-effects, of course).

In your example, you could just do:

```dart
class Actor {
  int x;
}
```

and get exactly the same effect.

What you want is, for some Actor "actor", to make the functions yourself:

```dart
var item = new PropertyItem(() => actor.x, (v) { actor.x = v; });
```

This [proposal about generalized tear offs](https://github.com/gbracha/generalizedTearOffs/blob/master/proposal.md#cons) is [approved](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/06/null-aware-operators-and-generalized.html) and will probably implemented soon and allows to closurize getters and setters like:

```dart
var item = new PropertyItem(actor#x, actor#x=);
```

Comment: Did the generalized tearoffs ever get implemented?

Comment: [It got removed in 2016](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27518). I'm not sure what the most up to date info is though.

[In the same issue thread](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27518#issuecomment-267433565): "The larger picture here is that the language team does want to add a better story for: Closurizing constructors, and Creating closures for other tiny common operations where an explicit closure feels too verbose."

Answer (score 6):

In Dart, the following:

```dart
class Foo {
  int _offsetX;
  int get offsetX => _offsetX;
  set offsetX(int ox) => _offsetX = ox;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```dart
class Foo {
  int offsetX;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the reference of that get / set function?  I need to pass those two function pointers to a class.  I'll update the question to make it more clear